# What options in /etc/mysql/my.cnf are applicable to percona-server-client-5.6?

Tags: mysql, percona

I installed percona-server-client-5.6 on Ubuntu; there is no mysql server installed on that same machine.

In `/etc/mysql/`, the only file is `my.cnf`. That file contains many sections of options and I am not sure which sections are applicable to the machine with only the client package installed.

I assume the `[client]` section of course, but why to the other sections exist at all? Will changing their values affect the mysql server the client connects to?

`my.cnf`:

```
[client]
...

[mysqld_safe]
...

[mysqld]
...

[mysqldump]
...

[mysql]
...

[isamchk]
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Those other sections are there because they are included in the template cnf file from the package provider (Percona).

You can create a user specific cnf file in your home dir that looks like the one below and they will get used when you run the `mysql` command:

```
[client]
user=$myusername
password=$mypassword
```

n.b. if you're going to store your credentials in a cnf file make sure you  set the permissions to 400.

Answer (score -1):

mysql install my.cnf as template with all sections and commented help information

for start work You generally will need only [client] section

for connect use command line like

```
user$ mysql -h 192.168.10.111 -u root -p
```